# Drop Down Menu out of Screen

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, styling

I have this problem with my drop down menu I cant seem to figure out how to move the drop down menu that shows when you hover above the "support" button, I would like to move it little bit to the left,the other half is sticking out of the screen and can't be seen.

here is the link to it.

```
[jsfiddle] http://jsfiddle.net/3ZzVT/1/
```

All replies and help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: The jsFiddle quality filter is there for a reason. Do not try to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3ZzVT/3/

Adding a `right: 0px` to the `.head_menu ul` selector makes the element position itself better underneath the nav item.

Answer (score 1):

Like this .head_menu ul give `position:relative;` and `right:0;`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZzVT/5/)**

**CSS**

```
.head_menu ul
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    right:0;    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.head_menu ul li ul
{
    display: none;
    width: auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    right: -15px; // I added this
}
```